# How can I connect to Microsoft Direct Access?

Tags: networking, vpn

My company has moved from Cisco VPN to Microsoft Direct Access. I was using `network-manager-vpnc` to connect from Ubuntu before. Can I use the same to connect to direct access? If not, how can I connect to direct access from Ubuntu (12.04)?